# Quick Volume with Cross Sections Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

So I was given the following prompt:

> "Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graph of $y=x^2$, the line $x=4$, and the $x$-axis. $R$ is the base of a solid whose cross sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are equilateral triangles. What is the volume of the solid?"

I understand how to find the area of cross sections that might be squares or rectangles, but I haven't worked with equilateral triangles before. I also understand that the formula for the area of an equilateral triangle is: $\frac {a^2\sqrt3}{4}$, but I'm a bit lost over how I'd find the area or even the sides of the triangle in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: To get the volume, integrate the cross-sectional area along the $x$-axis.

Comment: I understand that I have to integrate the area formula that I come up with, but I'm so confused about how I'd even find that formula.

Comment: I know how to find that formula with the cross-sections being squares or rectangles, but this is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the equilateral triangle cross-section is parallel to $YZ$ plane (perpendicular to $x-$axis). The base of the equilateral triangle is $x^2$ as it is between $y = 0$ and $y = x^2$.

So sides of equilateral triangle $ = x^2$ and height $ = \frac{\sqrt3}{2} x^2$

For a given value of $z$, $y$ will vary between $\frac{z}{\sqrt3}$ and $x^2-\frac{z}{\sqrt3}$.

The limits of $y$ come from the fact that at any given height ($z$) in the triangle if we drop perpendicular from two edges to the base, the distance from both vertices of the base to the foot of the perpendicular will be $ = z \cot 60^0= \frac{z}{\sqrt3} \ $.

So the integral to find volume should be

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{4} \int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt3}{2} x^2} \int_{\frac{z}{\sqrt3}}^{x^2- \frac{z}{\sqrt3}} dy \ dz \ dx$

If you integrate wrt $dz$ first, you will have to split the integral into two hence the choice of the order.

Comment: I think I'm understanding what you're saying, so what were you coming up with for an answer? I think I found one but I'd feel a bit better if I had some clarification.

Comment: You mean the final answer? That would be $\frac{256 \sqrt3}{5}$

Comment: Were you able to complete it? Do you need any further help with this?